# Is there a way to find a particular agent in a population?

Tags: anylogic

I'm currently working on a project in which I import a dataset with orders from different stores. There is also another dataset that was imported and that contains sequeces of stores ID's that each truck must perform when delivering goods. Each store has a GIS point assigned and the purpose is that the truck follows specified routes to deliver orders to different stores.

I have created an object order that has 4 parameters: quantity, store1, store2, store3. The first parameter indicates the amount of goods to be transported and the rest of the parameters explicit where these goods are to be delivered (i.e. store1 indicates the first store to which the truck must move to).
I now want these orders to be created but I need to find a way to relate the ID's that appear in the routes dataset with the agents that are already created from the stores dataset.
[stores database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvQlM.png)
[routes database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clqM2.png)

I tried to use the findFirst function as it follows:

```
for(int i=0; i < excelFile.getLastRowNum("Sheet1");i++){

double amnt=excelFile.getCellNumericValue("Sheet1", i+2, 4)
double a1=excelFile.getCellNumericValue("Sheet1", i+2, 5); ##Cell with the Id of first store
double a2=excelFile.getCellNumericValue("Sheet1", i+2, 6); ##Cell with the Id of second store
double a3=excelFile.getCellNumericValue("Sheet1", i+2, 7); ##Cell with the Id of third store

Store store1=findFirst(stores,Store->Store.storeId==a1);
Store store2=findFirst(stores,Store->Store.storeId==a2);
Store store3=findFirst(stores,Store->Store.storeId==a3);

Order order = new Order(amnt,store1,store2,store3);
```

I already tried different ways to define the condition "Store->Store.storeId==a1" but none of them worked and I keep having the following error message:
"Description: The method findFirst(Iterable, Predicate<? super T>) in the type UtilitiesCollection is not applicable for the arguments (Qstores, ( Store) -> {})."

Answer (score 0):

you are coding incorrectly, do this, replacing Store with x or any letter:

```
Store store1=findFirst(stores,x->x.storeId==a1);
```

also stores MUST be a population of agents, or a collection of agents of type Store

In your case it seems you have a database table called stores, and you cannot use that, first you need to create a collection with your stores, and THEN you are allowed to use findFirst

And don't call your database table with the same name as your population of stores. use stores_db or something like that for your database table names because AnyLogic otherwise gets confused

Comment: I tried to compute as you recommended, but the same error appeared. Just to clarify, "stores" is a population of agents of the type "Store". Each agent from this population was created by using a database called "sheet1". Should I create a collection and add all the stores then?

Comment: you can use findFirst with stores as a population of agents.. but your error suggest that you have a database table with the same name "stores"